# Como puedo calcular la fecha de vencimiento en javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, date, calculo

Necesito calcular la fecha de vencimiento de un contrato teniendo en cuenta la fecha de inicio de este y el numero de meses, datos que saco de dos inputs, el resultado necesito mostrarlo en otro input de tipo date al dejar el foco de la fecha inicio. Espero me puedan ayudar muy pronto, Muchas gracias de antemano.

Este es el javascript que monte pero no toma la operacion y luego la parte del html donde estan los campos que utilizo para calcular y el llamado de la funcion.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcularVenc(){
      // Creas la fecha 

      var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha_ini").value;
      var meses = document.getElementById("meses_contrato").value;
      var fechaVto = date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('+ '.meses.' month', strtotime(fecha)));
      //fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() + $("#meses_contrato").val());
      //$("#fecha_fin").val()=fecha.setMonth(fecha.getMonth() + $("#meses_contrato").val());
      alert(fechaVto);
      $("#fecha_fin").val(fechaVto);
    }
  </script>
```

```html
 <label for="inputName" class="text-muted">N° de Meses del Contrato:</label>

                      <input type="text" id="meses_contrato" name="meses_contrato" class="form-control" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" onkeypress="return controltag(event)" id="meses_contrato" disabled="true" required>

                      <label for="inputName" class="text-muted">Fecha Inicial Contrato:</label>

                      <input type="date" id="fecha_ini" name="fecha_ini" class="form-control readonly" required onfocusout ="calcularVenc()" >

                      <label for="inputName" class="text-muted">Fecha Final Contrato:</label>

                      <input type="date" id="fecha_fin" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha_fin" readonly class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: Según entiendo lo que debería hacer la función es tomar la fecha de inicio y sumarle la cantidad de meses que se ingresan en el input para luego devolverte la fecha resultante, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Si, exactamente, pero nunca lo he hecho a través de javascript, siempre lo calculaba desde php

Answer (score 0):

Mira el script que he hecho a ver si te vale así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <label for="inputName" class="text-muted">N° de Meses del Contrato:</label>

    <input type="text" id="meses_contrato" name="meses_contrato" class="form-control" id="meses_contrato" required>

    <label for="inputName" class="text-muted">Fecha Inicial Contrato:</label>

    <input type="date" id="fecha_ini" name="fecha_ini" class="form-control readonly" required
        onfocusout="calcularVenc()">

    <label for="inputName" class="text-muted">Fecha Final Contrato:</label>
    <span id="fecha_fin">dd/mm/YYYY</span>

    <script>
        function calcularVenc() {
            // Capturamos la fecha inicial que llega por el input
            let fechaInicialElemento = document.getElementById("fecha_ini");
            // Creamos la fechaInicial del tipo Date
            let fechaInicial = new Date(fechaInicialElemento.value);
            // Hasta que le sumemos los meses que indica el usuario son la misma fecha.
            let fechaFinal = fechaInicial;
            // Capturamos el valor en meses.
            var meses = document.getElementById("meses_contrato").value;
           // Se los sumamos a la variable mes
            let mes = fechaInicial.getMonth() * 1.0 + 1 + meses * 1.0;
            // Si la variable mes es mayor de 11 quiere decir que hemos saltado de año.
            while(mes > 11){
                // Al saltar de año le debemos sumar un año y restar 12 meses
                let dia = fechaInicial.getDate();
                let year = fechaInicial.getFullYear() *1.0 + 1;
                mes = mes - 12;
                fechaFinal= new Date(year,mes,dia);
            }
            // Creamos la cadena de texto fecha final
            var fechaFin = fechaFinal.getDate() + "/" + mes + "/" + fechaFinal.getFullYear();
            // Capturamos el elemento que la va a mostrar en el formulario
            fecha_finElemento = document.getElementById("fecha_fin");
            // Le asginamos la fecha de fin al elemento span que muestra la fecha final en el formulario
            fecha_finElemento.innerHTML = fechaFin;
            alert("La fecha fin de contrato es " + fechaFin);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Viene explicado el código por cada linea, espero que te sirva.Saludos.

Comment: Excelente, ya me arroja la fecha de vencimiento en la ventana del alert de manera correcta, pero no coloca el valor en el input de fecha_fin, que me estaría faltando, trate de asignarle el valor pero aun así no lo pone.